# Converting a comma-separated varchar to decimal

Tags: sql, type-conversion, decimal, varchar

I have a column in database like;

```
new_profittl
------------
45,1000
84,0400
156,6500
169,1800
...
```

My code;

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(new_profittl as DECIMAL(18,2)))
FROM new_hotelreservation AS R
WHERE DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, getUTCdate(), GETDATE()),R.new_salesdate)
      BETWEEN @bas AND @bit AND R.statecode=0
```

I have to sum this field. The field is NVARCHAR and separated with comma, not dot. so I can't sum this field. I tried to convert or to cast to decimal but it didn't. It gave an error 'Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.'.

How could I sum this field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the short run, this should do the trick:

```
sum(cast(replace(new_profitt1, ',', '.') as decimal(18,2)))
```

However, I can see any number of comlications coming up from this (multiple commas, no commas, embedded spaces, etc. etc.), so keep an eye on it.

Answer (score -2):

```
cast(replace(new_profitt1, ',', '') as decimal(18,2))
```

Above code will perfectly convert the varchar field containing comma to decimal.

**For example**:

> old_col   ->    new_col
>
> 1,951.13    ->    1951.13

Comment: The answer is duplicated

Comment: The commas in the ops question are not group separator but decimal point.