# Mysql truncated incorrect double value when CREATE TABLE AS

Tags: mysql, casting, double, truncate

I have a simple table called feed

| id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20,00 |
| 2 | 30,00 |
| 3 | 40,00 |
| 4 | abcdef |
| 5 |  |

Where price is a `VARCHAR` column. This is important. Now I can do a simple query such as

`select * from feed where price > 20` and it works, because of implicit type casting by mysql.

But if I do this query
`create table results as select id, price from feed where price > 20` It fails with `truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 20,00`

Even if I put `cast(price as decimal)` in the query in both the SELECT and WHERE, it still fails.

How can I suppress this error or fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a comma-separated varchar to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884054/converting-a-comma-separated-varchar-to-decimal)

Comment: What datatype do you want price to be in results?

Comment: @P.Salmon Either varchar or double/decimal. I don't want the data to be truncated, and I want to get the same results in the new table as when I do the regular select. So a value of `30,45` in the feed table would become `30,45` as varchar or `30.45` as decimal in the new table.

I can fix the types later in actual code. It's just about getting this table to work.

Comment: Did you check the duplicate link?

Comment: @P.Salmon It fixes it, only if the value can actually be an integer. If the value is actual text, empty string or null, it breaks.

Comment: It's worth amending your published sample data to include this new information..

Comment: *I can do a simple query such as `select * from feed where price > 20` and it works, because of implicit type casting by mysql.* No. If the price column value is `'20,50'` then this row won't be returned.